# How to start new page in function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Thanks for your answer

I try to call casper.thenOpen in a sub function, but It won't work.

```
casper.start(url, function(){
    console.log("Page Load");
});

casper.run(flow);

function flow()
{
  testOpen.call(this,'http://www.518.com.tw/talent-detail-1376860.html');
}

function testOpen(newURL)
{
    this.thenOpen(newURL);
}
```

My English is not good, If I say anything wrong, pleas forgive me :)

//======================================================

I'm trying to open a new page in a function.

Like this sample https://gist.github.com/observerss/3798922

CapserJS should call start with 'http://www.google.com' (Line 28)

then call start.call(this); (Line 40)
then call this.start(NewUrl, function();  (Line 34)

But line 34 call is not working.

I don't understand where is the different between my code and the sample I reference to.

Could any one tell me where is the problem?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: true,

pageSettings: {
     loadImages:  false,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
     loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4',
     clientScripts: ["documents/jquery.js"]
    }
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var google = 'http://www.google.com';
var bing = 'http://www.bing.com';

casper.start(google, function(status) {
   console.log("page loaded");
   this.echo(this.status(true));
});

function start(NewUrl){
    this.start(NewUrl, function(){
        this.echo(this.status(true));
    });
};

function flow(){
    start.call(this,bing);
    this.exit();
};

casper.run(flow);
```

Comment: You haven't said how it doesn't work. Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when I do everything that is described in my answer: https://gist.github.com/artjomb/32422923b57577463d0a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`casper.start` is asynchronous. You exit too early. You should either remove the `this.exit()` call or wrap it inside of a step function like

```
this.then(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

It is also not a very good style to schedule the majority of your code through `casper.run`. This is better (here in promise syntax for brevity).

```
casper.start(google).then(flow).run(function(){
    this.echo("DONE");
    this.exit();
});
```

Also, you should have `casper.start` only once in your script. You should use [`casper.thenOpen`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenopen) for opening subsequent pages.